# "My" Application on Windows 10 startup

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was checking my start-up programs on Windows 10, and I found one that I don't really know what it is.

[image]

Does anyone know anything about this? Is it bad? I cant open the source directory of it either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you recently uninstalled any programs that might have run on startup? Have you checked for viruses/malware?

Comment: I scanned with Malwarebytes and Avira, and the only thing i uninstalled lately is Android Studio.

Comment: I don't think Android Studio even runs on startup anyway, so that's probably not it. Try Right Click -> Disable from the context menu.

Comment: Yes i disabled it, I just don't know how to check what it is, and if its malware or something. Searching for "My startup" doesn't really help.

Comment: Yes, I found little in the way of helpful information. Most results came up with an entry called "Program" in a similar fashion, but nothing called "My". If Malwarebytes and Avira didn't find anything, you could be in the clear, but added scans from software like ADWcleaner or SUPERAntiSpyware might help ease your conscience as well. I can post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: Sure go for it, i'll try those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some brief searches through Google, there aren't many hits at all for a rogue startup process called "My". However, there are hits for things simply called "Program" in the startup processes menu. These can be leftover from applications that weren't quite uninstalled properly. All references to the name of the program are gone, but the startup process was thanklessly ignored. Not all is lost though;

If you have scanned your system with antivirus and antimalware programs, and they have come back clean, you're likely in the clear. To disable the process, go into your Startup Processes menu, right click the offending process, and select `Disable` from the context menu.

If you are still worried about a virus, it never hurts to get a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th opinion. Try running [ADWcleaner](https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/) from the coders at Malwarebytes, or a more full suite like [SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html)'s free scanner.

Answer (score 1):

CCleaner can identify unknown startup items.

1. Install CCleaner or run the portable version
2. Go to Tools → Startup
3. Also look under Tools → Scheduled Tasks, cause some malware will try to hide startup items there